# Migration statistics for February

Tags: discussion, migration, statistics

Using mod tools make this kind of list easier to make. Anyway, for February, here is the break-down of where questions were migrated away from ServerFault. I didn't go into any additional stats (mod-hammer vs. vote-to-5) or what happened when they got to the destination site since I'm on a crap network and that kind of loading may just kill it.

```
Destination   | Count
------------------------
StackOverflow | 14
SuperUser     | 133
Meta.SF       | 1
WebMasters    | 40
------------------------
Mod-moves to any site:
------------------------
AskUbuntu     | 5
Apple         | 3
WordPress     | 2   
Unix & Linux  | 8
WebApps       | 2
Security      | 1
```

209 migrated questions, of which 63.6% went to SuperUser. What's interesting to see is that migrations to WebMasters outnumber migrations to StackOverflow.

Moderators do have the ability to move questions to other sites, and 10% of 'em have been. If a question is a generic Linux question ([example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9768/hows-a-module-approved-to-be-included-into-the-linux-kernel)) that has to do with the inner workings of Linux and doesn't directly touch on sysadminly or end-usery things, mod-flag as a migrate to Unix & Linux. As you can see, we get a fair number of those. SuperUser-style questions regarding Ubuntu may be a better fit for AskUbuntu, although that question hasn't been fully resolved to my knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great data!

Just as a reminder, this is what we look at -- history of actual migrations and closes -- to determine which 5 sites (4 after you subtract meta) are shown by default in the close as off topic dialog.

Diamond mods can of course migrate to any site in the network, but we believe in

- limiting the # of close targets to some sane "don't make me think number"
- only "blessing" the close migration sites that are actually occurring in the wild with some frequency

Answer (score 3):

I may be wrong but I believe the Webmasters migrations are artificially high because a number of historical questions have been moved there, as that site didn't exist when those questions were posted. If I'm right then it's not a good indicator of likely future migrations.

Comment: It is higher, there was a whack of about 9 that were migrated about the same time. Even discounting those it's still our #2 destination.

Comment: Rootin tootin. I used the mod hammer heavilly on a bunch of mod_rewrite questions last month.

Comment: Webmasters questions will naturally accumulate here because it's a "web server" that people are dealing with and they think "webmasters" means "how do I put pictures of unicorns on my blog".